# redirection problem with mod ajp

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, ajp, tomcat

i have a redirection problem with mod ajp, that it always adds the application name before the desired page, for example:

if i requested the page:

http://myapp.com/mypage

it is converted to

http ://myapp.com/myapp/mypage, and i get a 404 error

i don't know why such behaviour occurs, this is the configuration:

```
<Proxy *> AddDefaultCharset Off Order deny,allow Allow from all </Proxy> 
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myapp/ 
ProxyPassReverse / 
ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myapp/ 
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myapp/
```

Comment: any help, i feel like lost here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ProxyPass /myapp/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myapp/ 
ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/myapp/
```

or

```
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/ 
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
```